# Call column name in Access table using "if" in php

Tags: php

Is this correct? Because it shows no records and also no error.

```
    if($SemYearSettings->getYearSem($Enroll)."Category" == $CategoryIDN && $SemYearSettings->getYearSem($Enroll)."Category" == $CategoryIDT){
    $QryFirstNursing = "SELECT *
                FROM Major, ".$SemYearSettings->getYearSem($Enroll).", ".$SemYearSettings->getYearSem($StudAccount)." 
                WHERE Major.DegreeCode <> ".$DegreeCode."
                AND ".$SemYearSettings->getYearSem($StudAccount).".AcctID = ".$AcctID."
                AND ".$SemYearSettings->getYearSem($Enroll).".MajorID = Major.MajorID
                AND ".$SemYearSettings->getYearSem($Enroll).".StudLevelID = ".$SemYearSettings->getYearSem($StudAccount).".StudLevelID";
    $resultFirstNursing = openQry($QryFirstNursing);
```

I'm trying to call the column name of the table in Access Database using the concatenation. "Category" is the column name. Is this valid?

Comment: try individual echo of what you compare in `if`. `echo $SemYearSettings->getYearSem($Enroll)."Category"` and `echo $SemYearSettings->getYearSem($Enroll)."Category"` also `echo $CategoryIDN` and `echo $CategoryIDT` to see the values.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response,.I'll try that one,.Thanks

Comment: You missed the `if` ending curly braket '`}`'

Comment: I'm sorry, input error,.There is } in the end..When I tried to echo the result is P20143_EnrollCategory..What I want is to compare the values in column Category with the value in $CategoryIDN. How to do this one??